# Tailing logs with Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I am new to Spring Integration framework and want to use it to tail  java log files in an application server, group line by line till I get a complete stacktrace, then send the stacktrace to another application. I have successfully tailed files by using (int-file:tail-inbound-channel-adapter), but I do not know which spring integration component to use in order to group the lines read by (int-file:tail-inbound-channel-adapter). Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Use an [aggregator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator) with a custom `ReleaseStrategy` and output processor.

Comment: I will learn more about aggregator and return in case of new doubts. Thanks for your attention, Gary.